# How can I find the least number of segments to get from start point to end point using Python?

Tags: python, list, tuples, enumeration, segment

So, I have start number, end number and a list of segments.

```
start = 10
end = 100
li = [(50, 60), (10, 20), (10, 40), (40, 60), (60, 80), (75, 95), (95, 100), (35, 45)]
```

And I need to find the least number of segments to get from point A to point B. If there are not enough segments, the program should indicate this.

I think that thanks to the illustration it will become clearer what I need.

[image]

In addition, I am not allowed to use any libraries or even `import`'s. Of course, the less memory and time is used, the better.

As for me, I've wrote terrible code:

```
for el in li:
    for el1 in li:
        if el != el1 and el[0] >= el1[0] and el[1] <= el1[1]:
            li.remove(el)

        elif el != el1 and (el[1] == el1[0] or el[0] == el1[1]):
            tmp = (min(el[0], el1[0]), max(el[1], el[1]))

            for el2 in li:
                if el != el2 and el1 != el2 and el2[0] >= tmp[0] and el2[1] <= tmp[1]:
                    li.remove(el2)
```

However, in my program there are three levels of nested loops, and in the middle of the third there is also `remove`, so my code do not work quickly and efficiently.

Comment: Presumably the end of one segment in the path doesn't need to be exactly the same as the start of the next? For example, you can follow (60,80) then (75,95), because 75<80? If so, then a greedy algorithm should work. If your current position is X, then find the segments (P, Q) with P<=X, and choose whichever one maximises Q. Repeat until you reach your goal.

Comment: @slothrop Yes, you are right, the end of one path segment does not have to coincide with the beginning of the next one. But I would like to understand how you can implement this in Python.

Comment: @KellyBundy That's why I am asking for some help

Comment: @KellyBundy A - start of path, B - end of path

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes, the result is 5.

Answer (score 0):

This code, while not being the fastest, should work well:

```py
def n_length_combo(lst, n):
    if n == 0:
        return [[]]

    l = []
    for i in range(0, len(lst)):

        m = lst[i]
        rem_lst = lst[i + 1:]

        remainlst_combo = n_length_combo(rem_lst, n - 1)
        for p in remainlst_combo:
            l.append([m, *p])

    return l


def mergeable(segs):
    if segs[0][0] < segs[1][0] <= segs[0][1] <= segs[1][1]:
        return True
    if segs[1][0] <= segs[0][0] <= segs[1][1] < segs[0][1]:
        return True
    return False


def merger(segs):
    has_grown = True
    while has_grown:
        has_grown = False
        for comb in n_length_combo(segs, 2):
            if mergeable(comb):
                curr_segs = set(segs)
                curr_len = len(curr_segs)
                curr_segs.add((min(comb[0][0], comb[1][0]), max(comb[0][1], comb[1][1])))
                if curr_len < len(curr_segs):
                    has_grown = True
                    segs.append((min(comb[0][0], comb[1][0]), max(comb[0][1], comb[1][1])))


def valid_combo(combo, start, end):
    # Merge segments
    segments = combo[:]
    merger(segments)
    # Verify if start and end are in the segment
    for seg in segments:
        if seg[0] <= start <= seg[1] and seg[0] <= end <= seg[1]:
            return True
    return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = 10
    end = 100
    li = [(50, 60), (10, 20), (10, 40), (40, 60), (60, 80), (75, 95), (95, 100), (35, 45)]
    best_comb = []
    for length in range(5, len(li)):
        for comb in n_length_combo(lst=li, n=length):
            if valid_combo(comb, start, end):
                print(comb)
```

Here we go through each combinations of segments by increasing length of combination and we check whether or not they are valid. In this example, we print them when they are, but we also could simply add a `break` statement.

I used help from Geeks for Geeks' [Combinations in python without using itertools](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/combinations-in-python-without-using-itertools/) to generate the combinations without using libraries.

For each combination, we try to merge every segment with each other to create the longest segments possible, and then we try to find a segment which contains the start and the end.

Comment: There are a lot of loops and also nested loops, assignings and even recursion in your code. It won't work fast, I think.

Comment: I admit that it may not be the fastest nor the prettiest, but it works fine. Although it may not be the fastest, it runs in 0.018s on average to find all the working combinations for your case, and only 0.0087s on average if we stop at the first solution.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your solution, but speed and uncluttered code is still important to me.

Comment: For the sake of curiosity, can you quickly run my and your solution on your end, to get comparable numbers?

Comment: Actually, there are some counterexamples for my code, so I think it doesn't make sense to do that.

Comment: Then, to be fair, this codes has the davantage of working. Also, while I understand your concern to limit loops and recursion, I think there is only so much you'll be able to do without using them. This is not saying my code is ideal in any way, but I do think it is not as bad as you seem to think.